# WordPress and BuddyPress SPAM prevention

Tags: wordpress, ip, buddypress

I am setting up a site using WordPress and buddypress with suffusion theme. All up to date. As per usual I have spammers registering and are banning them as the register. I ban their ip number on the htaccess file.
 Then I notice an ip number was actually coming from my hosting company and it so turned out that it is the shared hosting ip number, that my site is on.

So some person is registering, numerous times and the ip number is my shared hosting account ip number. Even thought I banned the number its still registering. I get the ip numbers from wordfence and bp register plugins.

I checked my host web stats on the control panel and it shows 174 vists and 446 hits from that ip number. I have checked the ip number on spam lists sites and it does not appear.

My hosting company, who are normally very good, says, 
The IP address: xxxxxxxx is a part of the shared hosting server: (named of host) which your website is hosted on. This is not a bot host or visitor IP address. I assume that either your website has some redirection loop or this is the script a part of your website such as cron script or similar.
There should be no point to block this IP address as this is not an actual visitor on your website.

What does this mean and how do I stop that ip number coming up on some registrations and is my script corrupt.

Comment: What script might be corrupt? What plugins are you using to assist or block registration?

Comment: Should this be migrated to ServerFault?

Comment: Try pulling down the site and loading it on your local machine. See if you get the same behavior.

Comment: This is not a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think that banning the IP address on your .htaccess file would be the best way to prevent people from registering on your site.

Have you tried using any spam prevention measures besides modding your .htaccess file?

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/buddypress-spam/

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
Using IP blocker in cPanel
Most hosting providers also offer the option to block suspicious IP addresses in WordPress. If you prefer this method, you can block suspicious IPs from your hosting account by following these steps:

Log into your hosting account
Go to the cPanel and go to the section called Security.
In this section, there should be an option that allows you to block IPs. On Bluehost, the option is called IP Blocker. Other hosting providers may name it something else.

Step 2:
check your website script maybe these Ip bots are operating from your directory.
check for any malicious code